# Bluetooth doesn't work "plug in a dongle"

Tags: bluetooth

```
systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

In settings I can't switch on Bluetooth:

> No Bluetooth Found
> Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Good afternoon, try turning off and on your computer rather than restarting it. It helped me. Good luck!

Comment: it doesn't help.

Comment: [this works](https://webwiks.com/techcorner/get-ralink-rt3290-bluetooth-work-in-linux/)

Comment: But after reboot module Ralink rt3290 (rtbth) doesn't run automatically and it's next issue.